# Pull column twice from same table without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following query (in a PHP script)

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT head FROM pages WHERE id='0') AS nullhead
FROM pages WHERE id='$id1' OR id='$id2'
```

It pulls out data for a given page, including the value of the head column. However, the head column may be NULL, in which case the value for which id=0 is used instead.

Is it possible to do this without the subquery on line 2, while still using only one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a self-join here (in this case, a cartesian self-join)

```
select a.*, b.head as nullhead
from pages a, pages b
where a.id in ( '$id1', '$id2' )
and b.id = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select `0` when `head` is `NULL` use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(head, 0)
FROM pages WHERE id='$id1' OR id='$id2'
```

Comment: Not quite what I wish, but thanks, I didn't know about the coalesce function. What I wanted was to get "head" where "id" is 0, not 0 when head is NULL